# Include fully-observed variables as a response or a covariate in multivariate normal imputation?

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a few questions regarding the specification of multivariate normal imputation model (MVNI):

Suppose I have the following substantive analysis model, and there is missing values in X1. I want to use MVNI model to impute X1.

```
Y = b0 + b1 * X1 + b2 * X2
```

In the MVNI model, I can include X2 and Y as response variable, such that Y, X1, and X2 follow a multivariate normal distribution.

**The questions:**

1. Can X2 and Y be included as covariates in the MVNI model for X1?
2. If yes, then the MVNI model only has one response variable, how can the MVNI model be specified?
3. What are the major aspects to consider when choosing between the two approaches?

**Reading material:** I read the Book (p. 129, reference below) that "*For fully observed continuous and binary variables, the conditional distribution for imputing the partially observed variables will be practically equivalent, whether they are included as a response or as covariates.*"

> Reference: Carpenter JR, Kenward MG. Chapter 6: Nonlinear
> relationships. In: Carpenter JR, Kenward MG. Multiple Imputation and
> Its Application (First Edition). John Wiley & Sons, Ltd. 2013.